# Storing data via facebook api

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I'm developing a game (similar gameconcept as QuizClash) for android using the facebook sdk.

The basic principle is like the following:

1. Player A chooses a friend of his facebook friendslist to play with
2. Player A answers three questions and waits until Player B has accepted and answered three questions as well (idle time between Player A and Player B can take up to 24 hours)
3. Player A & B both get to see the score

My specific question now is, can I store the states between a game as well as the final scores on the Facebook servers via the API? Or do I need to set up my own database to store the temporary game states?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up your own database. The Scores API is just one number you can store per game: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/scores